# Linking multiple auth providers with Firebase on Login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wish to link multiple auth providers on the time of user signin into the app . Firebase docs provides a method to link a new auth provider with logged in one but I wish to link on the time on login/signup so user can choose any auth provider without any hassles to link them manually .

Any suggestions on this . Please help.

Comment: I don't think that you can do this. Your app does not know the credentials of the user account. Therefore, can't do automatic sign in.

Comment: Lets say we check for his email id on firebase server and if it return yes then can we do it then using anything (idk) . Like many mobile applications and websites provide this feature (not sure what they are using) . So there must be a way someway or another .

Answer (score 2):

Linking accounts requires that the user authenticates with each of those accounts.

By signing in to an account/provider, the user proves they "own" that account at that provider. There is no way to link accounts without requiring the user to sign in to each account.

Comment: With all due respect, how then websites like github, flipkart etc do this. In that if we sign in from one provider, sign out and then use another provider they lets us in and automatically handles auth accounts linking without extra user interaction. My point being if we detect that a user email is in firebase db then we automatically links him/her with the current auth provider.

Comment: We shouldn't ask the person to login with their previous provider to link these auth provider they currently trying to sign up with.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dawn. Many of Firebase's feature come from developers such as yourself. If you'd like to file a feature request, fill out the form here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Thanks for the commen and I did asked the dev community at firebase using the link.

Comment: Any update since 2016? Has the dev community took your suggestion into consideration?

Comment: Still no update