# Firebase authentication: linking multiple provides

Tags: firebase-authentication

I followed the Firebase documentation to implement multiple authentication providers (Google and Facebook), and I am with the problem that I do not know how to solve.

Assuming my new User has Google providers and facebook with different emails is possible to perform the following login flow ?.

1. User enters the first app and resolves login with your Google account
2. Firebase create an account and link Google her provider.
3. The user exits the application.
4. User again performs login to the app, however this time he chooses the Facebook provider (which has different email Google).
5. firebase links the Facebook provider the account that is already linked to Google provider.

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase documentation has a complete page dedicated to account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking). The samples in the page link to a [Github repo where you can see the code in the context of an entire app that demonstrates it](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/AnonymousAuthActivity.java#L158-L176).

There's little use in use replicating the documentation here. If you're having trouble making a specific step work, share what you've done and the [minimal code that shows where you are stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear, but my problem is exactly reported by User here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103537/linking-multiple-auth-providers-with-firebase-on-login) .