# How do you link firebase accounts in firebase_auth 0.11.1 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I've successfully implemented Google and Facebook sign ins for Flutter using firebase_auth 0.11.0.  I need to implement the linking account feature for accounts that have the same email address.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);

final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

How/where do you catch the Firebase error (auth/account-exists-with-different-credential) that the account is a duplicate email and therefore requires the `linkwithcredential` function?  I've tried to catch the error on `signInWithCredential` and `_signInWithGoogle()` above to no avail.

Based on the example here:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/06256967e494e6d719023a249c8bdaae4b3ae065/packages/firebase_auth/test/firebase_auth_test.dart

`FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
 user = await user.linkWithCredential(credential);`

This is how you link the accounts, but my question is how do you determine that this function needs to be run?

Edit: for clarity, can I link the accounts when only one credential/session exists?  For example, the flow should be, sign in with Facebook, catch (ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL), and then link to Google.

Answer (score 2):

Get the list of provider IDs for the current user, if it has FB but no Google, then Google can be linked to it

`List<UserInfo> providerList = _auth.currentUser().providerData;`

---

//Capture the error for the signin with crecentials, check the type of error, act
  /// Possible Errors:

- `ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL` - If the credential data is malformed or has expired.
- `ERROR_USER_DISABLED` - If the user has been disabled (for example, in the Firebase console)
- `ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL` - If there already exists an account with the email address asserted by Google. Resolve this case by calling [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail] and then asking the user to sign in using one of them. This error will only be thrown if the "One account per email address" setting is enabled in the Firebase console (recommended).
- `ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED` - Indicates that Google accounts are not enabled.
- `ERROR_INVALID_ACTION_CODE` - If the action code in the link is malformed, expired, or has already been used.

`final onError = (exception, stacktrace) {`
`/*ERROR HANDLING*/`
`};`

`final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).catchError(onError);`

Comment: I've found the two scenarios working through this. a) If I enable One account per email address in the Firebase console, I can catch the error ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL with _auth.signInWithCredential, the question is how to link them from here because the user is never signedin, currentuser is null.  b)  If I allow multiple accounts in the console, it creates two accounts and I can pull the email from the provider data but the firebase user object itself has no email.  In this case currentuser.providerdata has the email but the firebase user, user.email is null.

Comment: My follow question would be is linkwithcredential a valid workflow after catching ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL?

Comment: I'm trying something like this, but since they've moved the linkwithcredential to the user, I don't have a current user to link 

    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .catchError((e) async {
      if(e.code == 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL')
        {
          FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
          user.linkWithCredential(credential);
        }
      print(e.message + "MESSAGE");
      print(e.code + 'CODE');
      print(e.details);
    });

Comment: I have this:
`    GoogleSignInAccount user = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      user = await _googleSignIn.signIn().catchError(onError);
if(user != null){
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await user.authentication;
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await _auth.signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        )).catchError(onError);
`

Comment: If you try to sign in a user with Google and you get ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL, you can notify the user that the FB account needs to be linked, you start FB sign in, after getting the credentials you get the current user user (already logged in with Google), and link Facebook to it, after linking them you should see both icons on Firebase

Comment: Thank you, I'm seeing based on the link I found in my answer below, you can only link while the user is logged in with the first service.  This is counterintuitive to me, but that seems to be the way Firebase does it.  I'm going to look back into allowing multiple accounts with same email and work through the challenges there.

Comment: When I do the link, I get an error "The email address is already in use by another account. "  . This is my call => return firebaseUser =
              await firebaseUser.linkWithCredential(linkCred);

Comment: "The email address is already in use by another account. " means you are trying to create another account with the same email. You can remove an existing account on firebase console -> authentication.

Comment: right now instead of using `ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL` i used `account-exists-with-different-credential`

Answer (score 2):

To link google and facebook, I'm using:

```
FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult = await _handleFBSignIn();
    final accessToken = facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token;
    if (facebookLoginResult.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
      final facebookAuthCred =
      FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: accessToken);

      final user = await auth.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCred).catchError((e) async {
        if (e.code == 'ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL') {
          var graphResponse = await http.get(
              'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,picture.width(400)&access_token=${facebookLoginResult
                  .accessToken.token}');
          Map<String, dynamic> profile = json.decode(graphResponse.body);
          profileData = profile;

          var email = profile["email"];

          final signInMethods = await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email: email);
          if (signInMethods.contains("google.com")) {
            final authGoogleResult = await googleLogin();

            if (authGoogleResult.user.email == e.email) {
              await authGoogleResult.user.linkWithCredential(e.credential);
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: So the user, in the case he has already a Google account. Will have to -Login with Facebook and then -Login with Google. No other way to link the accounts without letting the user log in in two services?

Comment: right now instead of using `ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL` i used `account-exists-with-different-credential`

Answer (score 1):

Based on this information: [Linking multiple auth providers with Firebase on Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103537/linking-multiple-auth-providers-with-firebase-on-login)

(If it is still accurate) my flow is unattainable, i.e. you can't link accounts without having logged into the first firebase account, e.g. Login to Google THEN login and link Facebook.

The user flow I need will need to be achieved by enabling multiple accounts for the same email.  Though this poses additional problems, the second firebase account user `FirebaseUser user` does not contain an email, `user.email` is `null`.  Though the `user.providerData` has the email.