# how to add email signin with phone signin or multiple signin providers together in firebase using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I've done the email sign in and also phone sign in once a user sign in but what's the function to connect the both of them with single user in firebase flutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use [linkWithCredential()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/linkWithCredential.html). It will work similar to what you see in the [Firebase Auth documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

See also: [How do you link firebase accounts in firebase_auth 0.11.1 in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260249/how-do-you-link-firebase-accounts-in-firebase-auth-0-11-1-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks btw I found the solution before you posted .

Comment: You are always free to answer your own question, or just delete it if it's no longer necessary.